# Jquery check previous radio button on ajax empty response

Tags: jquery, ajax, radio-button

I have few radio buttons. When you mark one of the as checked, ajax request performed. If response is empty, I need to uncheck this radio and mark previously checked radio.

For example:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function (e) {
   callAjax();
});
```

How can I add required logic to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function (e) {
   var prior = $(this).prevAll('input[type="radio"]').first();
   callAjax(this, prior);
});
```

`var prior = $(this).prevAll('input[type="radio"]').first();` returns the previous radio button regardless of the markup there is between them. Like if you have a markup like this :

```
<input type="radio" id="r1">r1<br>
<input type="radio" id="r2">r2<br>
<input type="radio" id="r3">r3<br>
.. etc
```

The `callAjax` function should / could look like this :

```
function callAjax(element, prior) {
    $.ajax(
        ...
        success : function(response) {
          if (response=='') {
             $(element).prop('checked', false);
             $(prior).prop('checked', true);            
          }
        }
    });
}
```

I cannot reproduce a real ajax call in a fiddle, but see this anyway -> **http://jsfiddle.net/qHc28/**